# Android prevent appearing sensitive data at task switcher without secure flag

Tags: android, task-switching

Android task switcher shows the recent application details with current onpause screen shot. For security reason, I want to remove this screenshot from the task switcher with out implementing secure flag functionality.

Comment: Please state your own research results or what you tried already.

Comment: Activity.onCreateThumbnail() method can do the help . But recently Its deprecated. Only Setting up secure flag can help us remove the application view while app moves to background. But the drawback of this flag is, it will replace the view by white back ground. I want to replace with custom image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: Customizing recent apps thumbnail (screenshot by default)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274289/android-customizing-recent-apps-thumbnail-screenshot-by-default)