# Android never call method onCreateThumbnail

Tags: android, android-activity, android-canvas, android-bitmap, android-thumbnail

Based on Android documentation, method [onCreateThumbnail](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateThumbnail(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Canvas)) is called before pausing the activity, and should draw into `outBitmap` the imagery for the desired thumbnail in the dimensions of that bitmap. It can use the given `canvas`, which is configured to draw into the bitmap, for rendering if desired.

The default implementation returns fails and does not draw a thumbnail; this will result in the platform creating its own thumbnail if needed.

When the method returns `true`, system will not use a standard thumbnail, but custom thumbnail drawn into the `canvas` is (or should be) used.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Window window = getWindow();
    // cleared by default, but let's make it explicit
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE); 
}

// @Override
public boolean onCreateThumbnail(Bitmap outBitmap, Canvas canvas) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateThumbnail");
    return false;
}
```

However, it seems that the **system never call this method**. Is there some special settings or flag needed to have this method called and being able to generate own thumbnail for the activity?

Comment: I haven't looked into this in quite some time. The only thing that I recall that we have control over is the action bar equivalent that appears at the top of our app's card (plus `FLAG_SECURE`).

Comment: From Activity documentation: "This method was deprecated in API level 28. Method doesn't do anything and will be removed in the future."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not possible to customize the activity thumbnail** which system uses in the recent apps preview.

The method `onCreateThumbnail` had been broken since Android 4.0.3, when its call was commented out (see the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/app/ActivityThread.java/#2776)).