# Why Android Pie recents task thumbnail blank for landscape activity?

Tags: android, landscape, android-9.0-pie, android-recents

How can I get the thumbnail to show for a landscape activity in Android Pie?
Seems that Google have mucked up their recents tasks.

Activity is in portrait orientation -> Thumbnail is ok.

Same activity is in landscape orientation -> No thumbnail.

[image: Activity is in portrait orientation. Thumbnail is ok.]

[image: Same activity is in landscape orientation. No thumbnail.]

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274289/android-customizing-recent-apps-thumbnail-screenshot-by-default

Comment: seen that before, but I don't need to customise the screenshot - it doesn't even show the default image.

Comment: in your screenshots only action bar is not appearing in landscape activity ,  which thumbnail u r asking for? please explain your problem

Comment: action bar not appearing because the landscape screenshot is completely blank.

Comment: for landscape activity u should use onConfigurationChanged in your activity and recreate view so your actviity will be appear same like portriat mode.