# How to show a black screen when an Android app goes in background

Tags: java, android, react-native

For security reasons I want to show a black (in dark mode) and white full screen (in light mode) when the app goes in the background.

The standard approach should probably be to use `FLAG_SECURE` but this will not cover the entire screen (e.g., if the status bar is of a different color you will see it) and the background color is not customizable.

After I also compared the solution created by common banks and finance apps like N26, Revolut, Unstoppable Domain, etc. I came to the conclusion that they are using something different. They are able to render a full black/white screen without content.

Which approach are these companies using?

I also tried to show a black view on top (listening to the onPause on the main activity) and removing it onResume and although the black view is added the screen shown in the recent apps is still the previous one.

I tried react-native and vanilla android apps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: Customizing recent apps thumbnail (screenshot by default)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274289/android-customizing-recent-apps-thumbnail-screenshot-by-default)