# Hide info in recent app screen with app logo to be shown but allow screenshot

Tags: android

I want to make recent screen of my app to be white with app logo in middle ***(recent screen means when you click recent app button to check which all apps are in background and you can kill either of them or all the apps)***. But user can take screen shot of my app screen.
Is it possible to do this?

Some of the approaches i have checked

- **WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE** this will make recent app screen white but not having app logo and users are restricted to take screen shots.
- Using **onPause** and **onResume** method to put white background and app logo but that also didn't work because system takes screenshot of app before calling onPause method so whatever i do in onPause will not reflect in recent app screen

Comment: have you checked this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274289/android-customizing-recent-apps-thumbnail-screenshot-by-default

Comment: yes I have checked the link @inkredusk but on window focus changed also if i put any view won't work.

Comment: Yes i found the solution. Will add as an answer to my question here